# Short story where society is divided by colored areas based on physical color & beauty

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A few years ago, I found a short story in the App Store on my iPhone and can't remember the name.

It was set in a dystopian world where everyone was beautiful & had amazing lives until they turned 18. Then each person went through a machine that assigned them a physical color, career and distorted features. Society was divided by actual colored areas. Your physical color/appearance determined the color you lived in - same color house, car, everything - and you stayed only within that colored area until you begin to advance in your life which created your beauty and advancement to a "higher" or more attractive color. The story followed one young man & how he didn't accept this way of living. He set out to destroy this new world.

Comment: See if this rings any bells: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/ShadesOfGrey

Comment: At first I thought this might be Red Rising as it has a lot of similarities in the colour aspect, but then the house and car and thing is not the same. Maybe it could point into the right direction?

Comment: @moonCat93 Wow, that looks like a good read too. Also close. In the story I’m looking for, everyone is beautiful, God-like features until they turn 18. Then they are “processed” through a machine to determine their color (status), career, etc & distorting their looks. Thank you.

Comment: @jo1storm Somehow, I accidentally deleted my reply to you, sorry. That sounds like a good read. Very similar. In my story, the color is physical indicating the person’s status & everything they own is the same color. Society is divided into colored areas. Thank you.

Comment: It make me thinks to *Wind on Fire* by William Nicholson, where the society is based on colors. But it was the whole family, and each member could earn points to make his family go higher or deeper. The story follows the twins Hath, Kestrel and Bowman. The one you describe seems to either have inspired or be inspired by this novel :)

Comment: @Lyzvaleska Interesting. A little similar. My story follows just one guy & his adjustment to his new life. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean it had its own app?

Comment: @Stormblessed No, it was a short story in a short stories app. I’m hoping someone came across it too. Thank you.

Comment: @Michelle I recommend looking through your purchases, to see what the app is; that would be really useful to narrow it down.

Comment: @Stormblessed That was the 1st thing I did but since it was a free story app, it isn’t in the purchase history. I’ll look again. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible the file is still on your phone, but not associated with the app?

Comment: @shoover How could that be? The short story was in a short stories app. The app has since been deleted. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what app you're using, but I have found leftover .epub files on the drive of my iPad after I have "deleted" the stories from OverDrive. The story gets removed from the app, but not from the file system.

Comment: @shoover Please forgive me but that sounds very complicated. It’s been almost 10 years that I downloaded a free short stories app from the Apple App Store. The story I’m looking for was in that app. It was deleted from my device less than a month after using it. I looked through my download history & it isn’t there. I appreciate the information.

Comment: Apologies; I was just trying to help with a possible alternative way to recover the story. Do you remember any other details of your acquisition of the story? Did you purchase it or was it free? Did you get it from a store or a library? Was it a professionally published work, or was it possibly a fan fiction?

Comment: @shoover No worries. I understand. Please see my previous responses on this thread for the answers to your questions. Thank you.