# YA novel where the world is divided by color

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dystopia

Read this book before 2013.

The protagonist (I think it was a boy) lived in a world where society was divided by colours and each colour had their own city/continent. Each of these colours had their own rules for that part of the world. The main character wants to either change his colour or make it so that all the colours are everywhere. He starts traveling between all of the colours so that he can learn about them while he looks for the being (? Or god? Creature?) that can make him change/make the colours be everywhere.

I remember that in one of the colours there was a limit of how many words someone could speak a day/week, another where everyone could eat whatever they wished for but in the end it was all made of the same thing, and another (blue I think) was submerged and you had to take a train to go to the dome underwater (in this one there was also a mattress that made it so you only had to sleep 4 hours instead of 8 so you had more time to dedicate to other things, I think it was to study).

They did manage to find the being in the end, (with the friends that they made during the journey, if I remember correctly) and it agreed with them to liberate the colours.

It was not a "let's overthrow the government" type of book. It was only a kid going for a adventure with their friends and in fact most of the book is only they learning more about how the others colours live. There wasn't, from what I remember, a caste system: every colour had their own ups and downs on why it was good to live there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to remember any details of the cover art?

Comment: Hello there! Unfortunately no. At the time it was not something I took much notice of on the books I read.

Comment: Similar question at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217790/short-story-where-society-is-divided-by-colored-areas-based-on-physical-color with suggestions in the comments that might help.

Comment: Were the people of that color (blue skin, hair, etc)? Could only see that color? Simply wore clothes of that color? The land itself was that color?

Comment: Also https://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/12-color-coded-sci-fi-fantasy-sagas/ might be handy.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Will look at the these places, thanks! From what I remember, the people themselves were not that color, but it was the only one they used on their day to day

Comment: I read this recently-ish (meaning after 2010).

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

The mention of "blue" as one of the colours of this segregated land had me immediately leaping to Divided Kingdom by Rupert Thomson, published in 2006.

[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/285825.Divided_Kingdom)

> One night a boy who comes to be called Thomas Parry is taken from his family, caught up in a comprehensive unraveling of what had been a united kingdom. Reacting to their country’s inexorable decline into consumerism, turpitude, racism, and violence, the powers that be establish four independent republics based on the perceived nature of the citizens assigned to each. These new partitions are reinforced with concrete barricades and razor wire.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_Kingdom)

> The former United Kingdom has been divided into four Quarters: Green (Scotland, the North-East of England and East Anglia); Red (the East Midlands, the North-West of England and Northern Ireland); Blue (Wales and the West Country) and Yellow (the West Midlands), each allocated a different personality type. Each of these personality types is based upon a different Humor: Sanguine is blood, Choleric is yellow bile, Phlegmatic is phlegm and Melancholic is black bile. Each country has a different way of running things: for example, the Blue Quarter uses canals, and the Yellow Quarter is industrious.

As you've recalled it isn't an "overthrow the regime" world or an escape to the outside type scenario. The main character that we follow around is given insight into each of the different regions by virtue of his job in the ministry.

> The protagonist is Thomas Parry, a government official for the Sanguines. He attends a conference in the Blue Quarter and visits a club called the Bathysphere where he sees his life as it was before the division. This inspires him to go on a journey across all the quarters to find out about his past.